# How do I connect mobile hotspot internet to red hat linux 7.2

Tags: linux, rhel, wifi-hotspot

How  do I connect mobile hotspot internet to red hat linux. I tried `nmcli con` command.

[image: here the network of mobile is also not visible]

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  Copy the output into a code block.

Comment: Would have done that but its not getting connected to internet.

Comment: @antarabhattacharya your comment made my day...(y)

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: have you checked whether wan is ON, `nmcli -t nm wwan on`

Comment: Error : 'networking' command 'wwan' is not valid

Comment: Do you even have a WiFi adapter in the system and firmware installed? `lspci`

Comment: @Jesse_b You need to learn to lay off the whip and stop treating those who are having problems with contempt.

Comment: @ajeh i have the wifi adapter in the system and firmware installed

Comment: @Jesse_b Then you are clearly abusing this forum and its members to vent personal grudges.

Comment: @ajeh:  I simply asked that pictures not be used and did not push after learning it was unfeasible for op to do so.  How could I have a grudge against a new user?  I think you are clearly reading way to much into a simple comment.  One that should always be made when images are placed into questions.

Comment: @Jesse_b I was rather referring to excessive downvoting to which either you, or your comment contributed. Stop.

Comment: Are you able to scan for the available AP through `nmcli device wifi list`?

Answer (score 0):

run these commands to ON wan and connect your broadband.

```
  nmcli -t nm wwan on
  nmcli -t con up id <Your Mobile Broadband Connection Name Here>
```

To check the status of your connection

```
  nmcli -p dev
```

For RHEL7

```
  nmcli device wifi con "ssid" password "<password>"
```

else try with `nmtui`

```
yum install NetworkManager-tui

nmtui
```

Comment: Object nm is unknown

Comment: which version of redhat are you using?

Comment: Red hat  version 7.2

Comment: @antarabhattacharya Try my updated answer

Comment: It is showing no wifi device found. But why

Comment: Post `lspci` output and `lsmod |grep` whatever your device name is. Something is amiss.

Comment: check  `nmcli device show`